# How many ways are there to arrive at point $E$ in $10$ minutes or less?

Tags: combinatorics

> Otto is traveling along octagon $ABCDEFGH$. He starts at $A$ and every minute, he will move to one of the adjacent vertices. He will stop once he reaches $E$. How many ways are there to arrive at point $E$ in $10$ minutes or less?

This question seems hard as time is the constraint here. How do I account for the time constraint here? my first approach would be to do case work with the amount of minutes: in $4$ minutes there are two possibilities, it is impossible for $5$ minutes, and then the casework gets more tricky.

Comment: In four minutes are there not two possibilities?  $A\mapsto B\mapsto C\mapsto D\mapsto E$ and $A\mapsto H\mapsto G\mapsto F\mapsto E$?  For six minutes, you will use a total of five clockwise motions and one counterclockwise motion (or vice versa) in such a way that the counterclockwise motion is one of the first four.

Comment: Yes, I made a typo.

Comment: Similarly, for $2n$ number of minutes, you can count the number of sequences of $n+2~$ $R$'s and $n-2~$ $L$'s where there are never four more $R$'s than $L$'s or vice versa except for the very end.  You could choose to look at this as a markov chain and calculate the corresponding matrix to an appropriate power if counting directly is too frustrating.

Answer (score 3):

You could draw something similar to Pascal's triangle where each cell is the sum of the two cells diagonally above it (except in columns D and F since you cannot come from E).

It might look something like this, and you then have to add up the numbers in the two E columns.

```
E   F   G   H   A   B   C   D   E
0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   1   0   1   0   0   0
0   0   1   0   2   0   1   0   0
0   1   0   3   0   3   0   1   0
1   0   4   0   6   0   4   0   1
0   4   0   10  0   10  0   4   0
4   0   14  0   20  0   14  0   4
0   14  0   34  0   34  0   14  0
14  0   48  0   68  0   48  0   14
0   48  0   116 0   116 0   48  0
48  0   164 0   232 0   164 0   48
```

Apparently [I calculated this](https://oeis.org/A060995) in 2001

Comment: I may even have shown the number of $2n$ length paths between opposite points of an octagon was $\dfrac{(2 + \sqrt2)^{n-1}}{\sqrt2} - \dfrac{(2 - \sqrt2)^{n-1}}{\sqrt2}$ in 1979 as 21st International Mathematical Olympiad, Problem 6.

Comment: Can you elaborate how this relates to the problem?

Comment: @user19405892: For example $\dfrac{(2 + \sqrt2)^{4}}{\sqrt2} - \dfrac{(2 - \sqrt2)^{4}}{\sqrt2}=96$ which is the number of paths which take exactly $10$ minutes

Comment: Sorry, I was referring to your original answer.

Comment: @user19405892: adding up the two E columns gives the answer as $2\times (1+4+14+48)=134$

Comment: What is the logic behind it though?

Comment: @user19405892 Each cell shows the number of ways of getting to a particular point in a particular time without passing through point E, by adding up the number of ways of getting to its immediate neighbours a minute earlier.

Answer (score -2):

To go forward 4 places he must have 7 steps forward and 3 backward. He must make 10 steps so the number of ways is ${10 \choose 7} = 120$. He could also get there by 7 steps backward and 3 forward so double this to get $240$.

Comment: This oversimplifies the problem and does not account for having arrived at $E$ early.  Note: Once he arrives at $E$ he stops.  Thus, $FFFFBFBFBF$ and $FFFFBBBFFF$ are technically the same path.